# JAXB: Unmarshal and set a part of attribute value

Tags: xml, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I am getting a long string as attribute and I want to unmarshal a part of it.
Here is what element look like:

```
<Party id="PARTYID_1341592540748_ed044bd3-b8b2-40f9-a679-4daa411ecc45">
```

But I want just `1341592540748` to be set as id.
Is it possible to edit @XmlAttribute string on the fly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend implementing an instance of `XmlAdapter` to contain this logic.  The advantage of this approach is that the XML conversion logic is kept separate from your domain model. An `XmlAdapter` is set on a field/property using the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/search/label/XmlAdapter

Answer (score 1):

One approach might be to do the conversion in a setter method, something like this (not tested):

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Party {

  @XmlTransient long id;

  // traditional JavaBean accessors for the long, _not_ used by JAXB
  public long getId() { return id; }
  public void setId(long id) { this.id = id; }

  // converting accessors for JAXB
  @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
  public String getStringId() { return String.valueOf(id); }
  public void setStringId(String idStr) {
    // extract relevant bit of the string and parse it into a long
  }
}
```